# Trying to count an aggregate result in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have produced a query that lists out some records from my source data (at the bottom of this)

My table setup is made up of 3 tables that look like

**tu_unit_tbl**

```
| unit_id | unit_name | unit_subject |
```

**sp_student_tbl**

```
| st_id |  st_fname  | st_lname |
```

**sp_test_tbl**

```
| ts_id |  ts_st_id  |  ts_unit_id | ts_session |
```

My query so far, **which works fine so far**, but I need to add a computed field onto it:

```
SELECT  U.unit_subject,
        U.unit_name,
        S.st_fname + ' ' + S.st_lname as sname,
        T.ts_st_id,
        T.ts_session
FROM sp_test_tbl T
JOIN sp_student_tbl S on T.ts_st_id = st_id
JOIN tu_unit_tbl U on unit_id = ts_unit_id

WHERE ts_st_id = 184318
GROUP BY unit_name, U.unit_subject, ts_session,  st_lname, st_fname, ts_st_id
```

It produces this:

if you notice, there are 3 rows.  The first two have the same "unit name".  I am looking to add a field to count the occurrences of these rows

```
unit_subject | unit_name                            | sname    | ts_st_id | ts_session
--------------------------------------
Mathematics  | Algebra, Patterns, and Relationships | Frog Man | 184318   | 2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
Mathematics  | Algebra, Patterns, and Relationships | Frog Man | 184318   | 2012-07-31 15:25:47.000
Mathematics  | Data, Statistics, and Probability    | Frog Man | 184318   | 2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
```

**What I am trying to get**

```
unit_subject | unit_name                            | sname    | **COUNT OF UNIT_NAME**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mathematics  | Algebra, Patterns, and Relationships | Frog Man | **2**
Mathematics  | Data, Statistics, and Probability    | Frog Man | **1**
```

Note that there are only 2 records now, because the first 2 were combined and counted..

This is an aggregate result, of course, and I want to count those aggregate items in a new field (called Count of Unit Name)

my attempts to put in a Count(*) field, or even `JOIN`ing to a subquery that attempts to count the fields does not give me a count of the aggregate, but rather, counts each item that I aggregated!

How can I count the repeating **unit names** in my result?

Here’s the Raw data: (the repeating data indicates a test session for a student. each record is part of a session)

```
select ts_st_id,
       ts_session
from sp_test_tbl
where ts_st_id = 184318
```

> ts_st_id  | ts_session
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:22:42.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:47.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:47.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:47.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000
>
> 184318    2012-07-31 15:25:59.000

My latest attempt (recommended by praveen) seems like it might work, but gives an error.

```
WITH CTE (unit_subject,
        unitName,
        sname,
        ts_st_id,
        ts_session)
AS
(
    SELECT  U.unit_subject,
        U.unit_name as unitName,
        S.st_fname + ' ' + S.st_lname as sname,
        T.ts_st_id,
        T.ts_session
    FROM sp_test_tbl T
    JOIN sp_student_tbl S on T.ts_st_id = st_id
    JOIN tu_unit_tbl U on unit_id = ts_unit_id

    WHERE ts_st_id = 1234
    GROUP BY unit_name, U.unit_subject, ts_session,  st_lname, st_fname, ts_st_id
)

select count(unitName) over (partition by unit_name)

Go
```

Generates the following Error Message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'unit_name'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'unitName'.
```

Comment: How does your query with COUNT(*) look like?

Comment: Im not at my desk,  but if I surround the queries with a count(*), the counts are 13, 3 and 21 for the first query, and 16 & 21 for the second.  its clear that the *source* data items are being counted, and not the *units* in my aggregate result

Comment: Place your query inside a CTE and then select count(unitName) over (partition by unitName)

Comment: just tried that, unfortunately it looks like there is some sort of syntax issue on the column name in the outer query. It certainly appears to be syntactically valid, but fails. (according to the example here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx )

(I put my CTE query and its result at the bottom of my question)

Comment: figured it out. needed to add *FROM CTE* at the end of my outer query select.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Common Table Expression did it.  Thanks **praveen**!

```
 WITH CTE 
    AS
    (
        SELECT 
            U.unit_subject,
            U.unit_name,
            S.st_fname + ' ' + S.st_lname as sname,
            T.ts_st_id,
            st_grade,
            T.ts_session
        FROM sp_test_tbl T
        JOIN sp_student_tbl S on T.ts_st_id = st_id
        JOIN tu_unit_tbl U on unit_id = ts_unit_id

        WHERE ts_st_id = 1234
        GROUP BY unit_name, U.unit_subject, ts_session,  st_lname, st_fname, ts_st_id, st_grade
    )

    select distinct unit_subject, unit_name, sname, ts_st_id, st_grade, count(unit_name) over (partition by unit_name) as TestSessions
    from CTE
```